Is it possible to set a CLSID on Electron apps built using electron-builder?
In the Electron docs related to notifications, it claims your application needs to have a start menu shortcut containing both an AppUserModelID and a corresponding ToastActivatorCLSID.
We're using electron-builder to create an NSIS Windows installer for our application, which allows you to set an appId.
After installation, when I check the start menu shortcut's details using electron.shell.readShortcutLink, I see that appUserModelId is correctly set to the appId value from the electron-builder configuration. However, the toastActivatorClsid property is an empty string.
The electron-builder docs don't seem to have any information about setting this clsid somewhere. How should I go about setting this property when the application is installed?
